# Modeling electric discharge in a game

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

I am working on a game with a basis in physics, abstracted and simplified but with an attempt to preserve the core of real physics.

For example, fire effects don't do direct damage, but generate heat. A character's temperature then rises by heat / thermal_mass. Every tick of the game, a hot character takes damage proportional to their temperature, whereas a cold character does not take damage, but becomes vulnerable to blunt damage and slips around more when moving. Temperature decays exponentially toward room temperature, via Newton's law of cooling.

I would like to have electrical effects with a similar level of realism. My current thought is that various electrical effects can cause static electricity build-up, as electric potential. Then, when two objects touch, there's an electric discharge, and we use the formula $$E = \frac{1}{2}CV^2$$ to determine damage, where we treat energy as proportional to damage. I guess, in this model, we treat the ground as a perfect insulator.

I am left with a few questions that I cannot find answers to:

1. How should static electricity decay over time? If you had an object suspended in the air with an electrical potential, at what rate would it fall back to 0? Is exponential decay a reasonable approximation for most macroscopic objects?
2. After a discharge, what should be the resultant potential? That is, if an object of potential V comes into contact with one of potential W, what is the potential of each afterwards? I figure this is solvable with conservation of energy, but I'm not really sure how to calculate electric potential energy for macroscopic objects.
3. If we want to have a single value to indicate how resistant/vulnerable a character is to electricity, is capacitance the way to go, as it's used in the formula above?
4. Is there a more realistic, while still being simplified enough for a fast-paced action game, way you can think to model electrical effects?

Comment: 'character' is made up of what? Is it a metallic object or human?

Comment: A character might be a biological or artificial lifeform, so either really.

Answer (score 1):

A basic model for discharge is the RC circuit, giving you a characteristic time scale:
$$
\tau = RC
$$
In a continuum medium, you replace these lump models by a continuous resistivity $\rho$ and permittivity $\epsilon$. The characteristic time is now:
$$
\tau = \rho\epsilon
$$
which is independent of the geometry assuming the medium is homogeneous.

In your setting, air is the medium. To get a decay of static charge, you cannot have the ground to be insulated since the charge needs to go somewhere. Using the vacuum permittivity $\epsilon_0 \sim 10^{-11}$ and resistivity $\rho \sim 10^{12}$ in SI, you get $\tau \sim 10s$.

To actually model a spark upon contact, you can imagine the shorting the two individuals so that their electric potentials equalise while conserving their joint charge. To do this, you'll need influence coefficients. Say you have two characters $i,j$, of respective voltage $V_i,V_j$ (with respect to the ground) and charge $Q_i,Q_j$, then:
$$
Q_i = C_{ii}V_i+C_{ij}V_j \\
Q_j = C_{ji}V_i+C_{jj}V_j
$$
with $C_{ij} = C_{ji}$. You get the final values:
$$
V = \frac{Q_i+Q_j}{C_{ii}+2C_{ij}+C_{jj}}\\
Q_i^f = \frac{C_{ii}+C_{ij}}{C_{ii}+2C_{ij}+C_{jj}}(Q_i+Q_j) \\
Q_j^f = \frac{C_{ji}+C_{jj}}{C_{ii}+2C_{ij}+C_{jj}}(Q_i+Q_j)
$$
You could imagine each character being inflicted damage proportional to the variation of electrostatic energy at each spark, given by:
$$
\Delta E = \frac{1}{2}\left(C_{ii}(V_i^2-V^2)+2C_{ij}(V_iV_j-V^2)+C_{jj}(V_j^2-V^2)\right)
$$

The influence coefficients highly depend on the geometry, but for your game, you could imagine them to be simple parameters, each character having a $C_{ii}$ (it scales with size), and interaction $C_{ij}$ when a spark is created between two character (can take it constant for simplicity).

For things to be interesting, you'll need to imagine a mechanism that creates charge separating (the analogue of fires for heat transport). Or else, eventually everything will discharge to the ground (in heat transport, the analogy would be that everyone would thermalise to the air). For example, you could imagine a cat charging itself periodically by triboelectricity and transferring its charge to the characters.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that the equalization of charge via a spark happens *very* fast.  Far faster than a single frame of a game simulation.  For gameplay reasons, you may find it more effective to make this charge flow unnaturally slow.  It might improve the game's aesthetic.